# Outlook 2007 Add-In

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm trying to assemble an Add-In and I'm wondering if it's possible to create an appointment in a Calendar programmatically in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this for samples...http://kbalertz.com/310244/Programming-samples-reference-items-folders-Outlook-using-Visual.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should to take a look here: [Outlook 2007 Sample Add-ins: Rules Add-in, Travel Agency Add-in, and Prepare for Meeting Add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226710.aspx)